# JSF custom Validator : no message rendered

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I want to display an error message using a custom JSF Validator.

After validation, I have no message rendered !

**EDITED**

I added more xHTML code, I have a popup with many fields and an `a4j:commandButton`.

The xHTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
<body>
    <script
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <ui:composition>
        <h:form>
            <ui:debug hotkey="x" />
            <h:panelGrid width="100%"
                rendered="#{not empty declarationReglementaireModel.detailCurrentDecReg.decReg.listLigneDipRecsDTO}">

                <rich:extendedDataTable id="listDipRec"
                    iterationStatusVar="itDipRec" rows="50"
                    value="#{declarationReglementaireModel.ligneDipRec}"
                    var="ligneDipRec" frozenColumns="1"
                    style="height:300px; width:900px;" selectionMode="none">

                    <rich:column width="35px">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="2">
                            <a4j:commandLink render="editGridDipRec" execute="@this"
                                oncomplete="#{rich:component('modifDipRec')}.show()">
                                <span class="icone icone-edit icone-align-center" />
                                <a4j:param value="#{itDipRec.index}"
                                    assignTo="#{declarationReglementaireModel.currentLigneDipRecIndex}" />
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                    target="#{declarationReglementaireModel.currentLigneDipRec}"
                                    value="#{ligneDipRec}" />
                            </a4j:commandLink>

                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="F106" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{ligneDipRec.lbValeurRubriqueF106}">
                        </h:outputText>
                    </rich:column>

                </rich:extendedDataTable>
            </h:panelGrid>


            <rich:popupPanel header="Données modifiables" id="modifDipRec"
                domElementAttachment="form" autosized="true" zindex="500"
                left="auto" top="auto">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="editGridDipRec">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="6" cellspacing="10"
                        styleClass="criteresSaisie" rowClasses="critereLigne"
                        columnClasses="titreCourtColonne,,titreCourtColonne,,titreCourtColonne,">
                        <h:outputLabel for="DipRecDtLigne" value="Date ligne fichier Dip " />
                        <h:outputText id="DipRecDtLigne"
                            value="#{declarationReglementaireModel.currentLigneDipRec.dtLigneDipRec}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="Europe/Paris" />
                        </h:outputText>



                        <h:outputLabel for="DipRecLbF106" value="F106 " />
                        <h:inputText id="DipRecLbF106"
                            value="#{declarationReglementaireModel.currentLigneDipRec.lbValeurRubriqueF106}">
                            <f:validator validatorId="checkvalidedouble" />
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:messages id="DipRecLbF106_message" for="DipRecLbF106" />


                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <div align="right">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="8">
                                <a4j:commandButton value="Enregistrer"
                                    action="#{rechercheDecRgltCtrl.enregistrerLigneDipRec}"
                                    render="listDipRec DipRecLbF106_message" execute="modifDipRec"
                                    oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity==null}) {#{rich:component('modifDipRec')}.hide();}" />
                                <a4j:commandButton value="Annuler"
                                    onclick="#{rich:component('modifDipRec')}.hide(); return false;" />
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </div>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>

            </rich:popupPanel>
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

The Validator

```
public void validate(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uIComponent, Object object) throws ValidatorException{
    String enteredValue = (String)object;
    if(enteredValue.contains(",")){
        enteredValue = enteredValue.replace(",", ".") ;
    }
    boolean isANumber = false;
    try {  
        double d = Double.parseDouble(enteredValue);
        isANumber = true;
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {  
        isANumber = false;
    }
    if (isANumber == false) {
        FacesMessage msgErreur = new FacesMessage("La valeur n'est pas un nombre valide.") ;
        msgErreur.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR) ;
        facesContext.addMessage(null, msgErreur) ;
        throw new ValidatorException(msgErreur);
    }
}
```

faces-config

```
<validator>
  <validator-id>checkvalidedouble</validator-id>
  <validator-class>xx.xxx.xxxxxx.model.DoubleValidator</validator-class>
 </validator>
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you have specified `render="listDipRec"` in the submit button, you should add also the panel body id `editGridDipRec`, in order to redisplay the validation message.

Comment: I removed the render property, and no changes

Comment: You have not to remove render attribute, change it to: `render="listDipRec editGridDipRec".

Comment: Sorry. Can you this test, set `render="listDipRec editGridDipRec"`, and remove the `oncomplete' javascript. do the test with invalid value.

Comment: no chance! It doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing another string argument to the FacesMessage constructor, that second string is the one that will be displayed on the client side.

```
FacesMessage msgErreur = new FacesMessage("La valeur n'est pas un nombre valide.", "validation error msg") ;
```

Comment: Did you define a form element around your form? Otherwise no action will be triggered.

Comment: Yes I have a form element, I can save if I enter a double, but when I put a string nothing happens!

Comment: Did you register your validator? @FacesValidator(value = "checkvalidedouble") I dont see the directive in the source code, did you give the xml configuration for it?